# Spring web application: executing common code before entering RequestMapping in controller

Tags: java, spring

I have a web application developed with Spring 2.5. The application has numerous controllers, containing GET and POST request methods, which are marked with RequestMapping annotations, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

I would want to execute some code before each such request, without modifying the existing controllers. How can I accomplish this, if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a `HandlerInterceptor`.  These "crosscut" your controllers. See this [Spring docs for more info](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor).

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here but weren't HttpFilters (that can intercept requests) designed for the same thing?

Comment: Yes, but they're not very Spring-friendly